# array values do not work as expected

Tags: php

I've a soap function which expects 3 parameters that should be passed as strings with quotes.

`function('id','username','password');`

and in another hand i've an array which contains :

`[0] = > "'id','username','password'"`

`[1] = > "'id','username','password'"`

`....`

when i echo $array[0] out put is 'id','username','password' and when i use `function('id','username','password');` there is no problem but when i use
`function($array[0]);` it won't work.

i tested my array with echo, die, print_r ... the output is the same as the function expects!!!!

any help ?

thanks ; )

Comment: There is a difference between passing three distinct parameters, or one string... PHP does not magically transform the string into three parameters, not matter what's the content of the string.

Comment: why you're not changing the way you call function and do it properly with function signature ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because **it can't work**. If you have a function that needs 3 parameters, you can't pass a single parameter. Also if is an array that contains the 3 parameters you need, the function still want and need 3 parameters. Thus, if you give the function an array, it will use just the array as the first one (so you'll have an unexpected behavior) and take the second and the thirs as NULL.

It's true that php is a little bit magic, but can't do miracles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the signature of your function.

```
function('id','username','password');
```

is a function with three parameters.

```
function($array[0]);
```

is a function with only one parameter.